# Delete all rows except for the oldest 20 for a single user

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table with columns:

```
id, username, createdat(timestamp).
```

How do I delete all rows for a single user except the oldest 20?

So basically rows for other users should be untouched.

I know the code below is wrong but still wanted to share what I have so far. Any input or suggestion is welcome.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tableA
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            tableA
        WHERE
            username = 'abcdefg'
        ORDER BY id ASC
        LIMIT 20)
```

Comment: thank you! I appreciate the edit!

Comment: postgresql. Are you implying the queries will be different if I were using mysql?

Comment: thanks! Didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.

```
DELETE FROM
  tableA
WHERE
  id NOT IN(
    SELECT 
        id
    FROM
        tableA
    WHERE
        username = 'abcdefg'
    ORDER BY createdat ASC LIMIT 20)
  AND
    username = 'abcdefg'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing a `DELETE` with a left join to a subquery which identifies the 20 records for a given use which should *not* be deleted.

```
DELETE a
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM tableA
    WHERE username = 'abcdefg'
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 20
) b
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL AND
      a.username = 'abcdefg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `delete` and a `left join`.

```
DELETE FROM a USING tableA a
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        id
    FROM
        tableA
    WHERE
        username = 'abcdefg'
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 20) b ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE
    b.id IS NULL AND a.username = 'abcdefg';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Common Table Expression like this:-

```
;WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY username ORDER BY createdat   DESC) UserLevelId
    FROM [YourTable]
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.UserLevelId > 20
AND CTE.username IN (........)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Limit to whatever User you want by adding :-

WHERE username IN (........)